# Geo Nodes - Align A Curve With Outside Of Bounding Box

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to make a comic book speech bubble in Geo Nodes. I have the text and bubble working, but *I can't figure out how to align a triangle to the outside of the bubble for the tail.* I have it aligned to the center of the bubble and it seems like I need to feed the Y transform with the bounding box somehow. Any advice is appreciated! File is here: [word_bubble.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2xbisrn5r9qze6u/word_bubble.blend?dl=0)

[image: stubborn triangle]

Answer (score 2):

I recommend instead of compositing a triangle on top of a circle, you just displace a vertex of a circle:

[image]

[image]

Alternatively: [image]

It does affect the width of the tail, and if you want to control that independently of the circle resolution, you would need to rearrange vertices of the circle.

This will allow to control the tail independently from the resolution of the circle:

[image]

Inputs can be [converted to degrees $°$](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/283778/60486):

[image]

[image]

**If you really want to just spawn a triangle:**

[image]

Comment: This is amazing! There's too much I don't understand about your group input node/s for me to get it to work but ... wow! Super impressive. I appreciate your taking the time.

Comment: @kopi_bon see the last screenshot, it's easier.

Comment: That is the same way I approached it with curve circles in my original example. The circle scales to match text positioned inside it based on the bounding box. More text = bigger circle. The problem is that the tail detaches or is absorbed when the circle is scaled up or down. Thanks again for your time... I'll keep working on it.