# How to create a ° degree field in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

Some nodes like **Vector Rotate** or **Mapping** have scalar and vector fields with $°$ symbol in them:

[image]
[image]

This also affects how the value is stored in memory – without the symbol it is stored basically without a change, but degrees are stored by being multiplied by ${π\over180} = 0.017453...$:

[image]

So I need to add "Degrees" to the field name to make it clear I ask for a value in degrees, and I need to divide it by `0.017453` or use *Math: To Degrees* node. How do I instead just set the input to display a value in degrees?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258623/how-to-add-units-in-the-input-parameters-of-geometry-nodes-properties-panel

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272070/what-is-the-parameter-forcing-a-node-input-defined-as-float-to-use-degree-unit-f

Comment: @quellenform could you close it as a duplicate of both? I don't know if I can link to both posts as a duplicate, but one is earlier, and has a methodology on creating it, the other has python information but unfortunately Gordon Brinkmann deleted the answer (we have to ask him to undelete)

Comment: Actually also https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/271457/60486

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a setting in UI or Python API, but you can create a degree° input by connecting a placeholder *Group Input* socket into an existing degree° field:

[image]

Unlike with the technique to create constant inputs not accepting attributes in the modifier stack, here the degrees will stay even after you disconnect them from the degree fields.